# Prefix Git Status File Path with particular string

Tags: python, git, awk, sed, git-status

I do `git status --short` at the root (of the Repository), and it lists the file path relative to the root like as follows:

```
M NumericalProgramming1Src/FloatingPointNumber.md
M NumericalProgramming1Src/NumericalProgramming.md
```

I want to prefix all the path with a value stored in a variable: `CustomPrefix=My/Path/To/Root/` as follows

```
M My/Path/To/Root/NumericalProgramming1Src/FloatingPointNumber.md
M My/Path/To/Root/NumericalProgramming1Src/NumericalProgramming.md
```

How could I achieve this?

NOTE: Sometimes `git status` has more than one character in the beginning.

Comment: You could pipe it to `sed "s~[ ]~ ${CustomPrefix}~"`

Comment: @revo Doesn't work in this case: See NOTE (in the question)

Comment: This looks for very first space character. Do you mean that space character could not exist?

Comment: sometimes there are other characters apart from space like DM or DD or ??, etc

Comment: It doesn't matter unless space isn't there. Current accepted answer also assumes there is at least one space character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With awk you simply call:

```
custom="/test/"
git status --short | awk -v cp="$custom" '{$2=cp$2}1'
```

For example, while `git status --short` yields

```
M org/languagetool/resource/de/added.txt
```

The above  command yields:

```
M /test/org/languagetool/resource/de/added.txt
```

Comment: How can we use bash variable `CustomPrefix` inside `awk` command instead of `/custom/prefix/`? I am asking because the string stored in this variable changes value in a `for` loop.

Comment: I have modified my answer accordingly; First, I set a new shell variable `custom` which I use inside my awk command via `-v cp="$custom"`